# Screen Recorder for Freya

Tags: release-freya, screenshot

Recently I installed istanbul Screen recorder from Software center. But its not working for me. even many commented there its not opening. So someone suggest me good screen recorder and good to use it on Freya

[image]

Comment: Which app you have downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam).

Install from software center.

Comment: works like charm

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [Vokoscreen](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611034812/https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreen) (screenshots included on GitHub page).

Install from software center

[image: img]

Comment: This one also nice. But i like to use lite weight one. So Kazam is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [recordMyDesktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtk-recordmydesktop/).

Install from software center.

[image: img]

Comment: Good app but it was discontinued seven years ago.